# Why does sorted() put 9 after 84 and 878?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
numbers = ['3','1','6','5','4','4','3','2','1','4','3','5','4','9','84','7','878','6']
counts = dict()
for number in numbers:
    counts[number] = counts.get(number, 0) + 1
print counts

for k,v in sorted(counts.items()):
    print k,v
```

---

Output:

```
{'878': 1, '1': 2, '3': 3, '2': 1, '5': 2, '4': 4, '7': 1, '6': 2, '9': 1, '84': 1}
1 2
2 1
3 3
4 4
5 2
6 2
7 1
84 1
878 1
9 1
```

Why is 9 the last one instead of 84 and 878?

Comment: your question is really messy :/

Comment: Because `'9' > '878'` is True. You need to convert keys to integers first.

Comment: You're sorting strings, not numbers.  If you want a numeric sort, convert the strings to numbers first.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you could also use `collections.Counter`

Comment: thank you all for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it compares lexicograhically. And '8' of '878' comes before '9' in lexicographical order. You are comparing as strings and not integers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have put your numbers in as strings they are sorted lexicographically which puts things in order by the characters of the string. So '9' is compared to the first '8' of '898' and thus comes after it.

You can get a more natural sort order by using a package such as [Natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) which can be installed via PyPi.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are comparing strings and you want to compare numbers.